# Patchwork package - joining three graphs

Tags: r, patchwork

I want to join three graphs with the patchwork package in R. I have also given an example that I prepared with Excel.
I tried this code, but it didn't work.

```r
library(patchwork)
patch_design <- c(area(1, 1, 1, 1),
                  area(1, 1, 1, 2),       
                  area(1, 3, 1, 3)) 
graph1 + graph2 + graph3 + plot_layout(design= patch_design)
```

I am able to make a graph but i could not able to keep the graph-a to its original size. [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that with `{pathcwork}` layouts, you generally deal with relative measures and ratios, not absolute sizes. And grid definition with `area()` goes like:

```r
area(top, left, bottom, right)
```

, absolute values starting from top-left corner, values themselves define the layout grid size (i.e. if you only use `1` for all your `top` and `bottom` values, you'll end up having a single-row grid)

In many cases, it's more straightforward to describe the layout as a string, i.e. for the one in your image, it might take a form of

```
11111
22233
```

or

```
111111
222233
```

You can use almost any symbols you like, `#` is a placeholder for empty grid cell, just be aware of the sorting order or your plots might not end up where you expected.

Let's start with the layout in question:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(patchwork)

## prepare example plots
ggplaceholder <- function(text, color){
  ggplot() + 
    geom_tile(aes(x = 0, y = 0, width = 1, height = 1), fill = color, alpha = .5) +
    geom_text(aes(x = 0, y = 0, label = text), size = 10) + 
    theme_minimal() +
    theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = "transparent"))
}

graph1 <- ggplaceholder("graph 1", "red")
graph2 <- ggplaceholder("graph 2", "green")
graph3 <- ggplaceholder("graph 3", "blue")

# current patch design, 
# 1x3 gird (single row x 3 columns), 
# grahp2 covers graph1:
patch_design <- c(area(1, 1, 1, 1), # 1 cell  for g1, from top-left to top-left 
                  area(1, 1, 1, 2), # 2 cells for g2, from top-left to top-middle 
                  area(1, 3, 1, 3)) # 2 cell  for g3, from top-right to top-right 
graph1 + graph2 + graph3 + plot_layout(design = patch_design)
```

[image]

Changing it to 2 row layout:

```r
# 2x5 grid
patch_design <- c(area(1, 1, 1, 5), # 5/5 of first row for g1
                  area(2, 1, 2, 3), # 3/5 of 2nd row for g2
                  area(2, 4, 2, 5)) # 2/5 of 2nd row for g3
graph1 + graph2 + graph3 + plot_layout(design = patch_design)
```

[image]

And the same with string definition:

```r
# instead of area(), you can define a layout grid with a string, 
# might be easier to follow and debug;
# identical to previous 2x5 grid:
patch_design_txt <- c("11111
                       22233")
graph1 + graph2 + graph3 + plot_layout(design = patch_design_txt)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-09-03 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

I am able to make a graph but i could not able to keep the graph-a to its original size. [image]

Comment: It's perfectly fine to answer your own questions, but please keep the answer section only for answers, you can (and should!) always change your question to add any additional information.